# Making points count automatically when zooming out in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features, vector-layer, count

[image]

Can I make the point count itself when there are too much stacked up points in one area when I zoom out my map?

I want my output e.g. Area of ganli points to be like this when i zoom out

[image]

Water point functionality image is not mine i just post it for sample.

Comment: Thank you very much this is what i`ve been looking for!

Comment: Welcome. Please, take a moment to read https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [Point Cluster Renderer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=point%20cluster%20renderer#point-cluster-renderer).

> **Point Cluster Renderer**
>
> Unlike the Point Displacement renderer which blows up nearest or
>   overlaid point features placement, the Point Cluster renderer groups
>   nearby points into a single rendered marker symbol. Based on a
>   specified Distance, points that fall within from each others are
>   merged into a single symbol. Points aggregation is made based on the
>   closest group being formed, rather than just assigning them the first
>   group within the search distance.
>
> From the main dialog, you can:
>
> - set the symbol to represent the point cluster in the Cluster symbol; the default rendering displays the number of aggregated
>     features thanks to the @cluster_size variable on Font marker symbol
>     layer.
> - use the Renderer drop-down list to apply any of the other feature rendering types to the layer (single, categorized, rule-based…). Then,
>     push the Renderer Settings… button to configure features’ symbology as
>     usual. Note that this renderer is only visible on features that are
>     not clustered. Also, when the symbol color is the same for all the
>     point features inside a cluster, that color sets the @cluster_color
>     variable of the cluster.
>
> [image]

For example usage, see also the blog post by @underdark "[Even more aggregations: QGIS point cluster renderer](https://anitagraser.com/2017/06/13/even-more-aggregations-qgis-point-cluster-renderer)"